# android arraylist sort

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have an string arraylist with values like

```
2.25mm
2.75mm
5mm
5.5mm
```

When sorting the values that do not have decimal place sort incorrectly.
5.5mm proceeds 5mm where 2.25mm correctly proceeds 2.75mm

I have not had any experience with  comparator so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are sorting your entries as `String`, its not behaving as numeric sorting  as in character notiation, `.` (ASCII 46) comes before `m`(ASCII 109) hence `5.5mm` is moved up than `5mm`.

Create another decimal point list by stripping the `mm`, sort the new decimal list as below:

```
      List<BigDecimal> decimalList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
      for(String elem: myList){
         decimalList.add(new BigDecimal(elem.substring(0, elem.length()-2)));
      }
      Collections.sort(decimalList);
```

If you want, recreate your sorted **string** list back as:

```
      myList.clear();
      for(BigDecimal elem: decimalList){
          myList.add(elem.doubleValue()+"mm");
      }
```

Comment: @user1706269: If this was helpful, don't forget to accept the answer(click arrow next to the votes).

Comment: Today I was allowed to accept answers for the first time so I've come back to reward you, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You're sorting these as strings, and the character `m` comes before the character `.`.

It'd probably be easier just to remove the `mm` and to sort parsed `BigDecimal` values.